# volatile and const pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants, volatile

I saw this code snippet

```
const volatile int * volatile * const X;
```

but I can't understand what does the second * means.

I understand that

const volatile int * volatile const X;

means a volatile const integer pointer  to a volatile const data.

Comment: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: @hmjd Put it as an answer and append the output from the site. If anyone else do this, I'll downvote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A useful site for understanding non-trivial C declarations is [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).

The description for:

```
const volatile int * volatile * const X;
```

from *cdecl* is:

> declare X as const pointer to volatile pointer to const volatile int